# SAQL to find the remaining days in the year?

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I want to found the count of days remaining in the year in SAQL .

```
q= foreach q generate daysbetween(toDate(date_to_epoch(year_start_day))-now()) as 'daysRemaining'
```

I want apply formula 365-now() in saql

Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to calculate each date's distance to the end of the year...

```
q = foreach q generate 
  daysBetween(
    toDate('DATA-DATE-FIELD', "yyyy-MM-dd"), 
    year_last_day(toDate('DATA-DATE-FIELD', "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  ) as 'EOY Distance';
```

I just tested it and it seems to work out:

```
Date       EOY Distance
...
2014-12-30 1
2014-12-31 0
...
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_lastday.htm